# tensorflow_probability: TransformedDistribution not accepting event_shape and batch_shape arguments

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-probability

In version 0.11.0 of Tensorflow Probability, I can define a `TransformedDistribution` as follows, indicating event and batch shape:

```
mvn = tfd.TransformedDistribution(normal, scale_lin_op, event_shape=[4], batch_shape=[2])
```

However, in the current version (0.12.1 as of the writing of this post), the `event_shape`and `batch_shape` arguments seem to have been deprecated, as the previous line produces the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'event_shape'
```

**QUESTION: How should the event and batch shapes be overridden in the current versions?** Is there some workaround or known alternative?

---

Note for reproducibility:
This is how I define a simple distribution and a bijector:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf
tfb = tfp.bijectors
tfd = tfp.distributions

# Define simple normal distribution
normal = tfd.Normal(loc =0., scale=1.)

# Define bijector based on a linear operator 
tril = tf.random.normal((2, 4, 4))
scale_low_tri = tf.linalg.LinearOperatorLowerTriangular(tril)
scale_lin_op = tfb.ScaleMatvecLinearOperator(scale_low_tri)
```

Remark: I know that doing `mvn2 = tfd.MultivariateNormalLinearOperator(loc=0, scale=scale_low_tri)` is equivalent and yields the correct batch and event shapes, but what I would like to know is what is the "new" way of overriding the event and batch shape when using `TransformedDistribution`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tfd.Sample` to sample extra event dimensions.

At the time of the change, there wasn't a suggested way to override the underlying batch shape, other than "use larger parameters for the distribution" like you have identified. However, the newly added (see `pip install tfp-nightly`), `tfd.BatchBroadcast` enables sampling a larger batch shape.

If you can only depend on a release, your best bet is what you have (or directly `MultivariateNormalTriL` and skip the `LinearOperator` bit).